# How to pass --pod-manifest-path to the kubelet quickly, without creating a new configuration file?

Tags: kubernetes, kubeconfig

Running `kubelet --pod-manifest-path=/newdir` returns errors.

It's not clear to me where I can add the `--pod-manifest-path` to a systemd file on **Ubuntu**. I know for `v1.12` there is the KubeletConfiguration type but I am using `v1.11`.

Comment: How did you provision your cluster?

Comment: I'm practicing troubleshooting. Where exactly should I look to apply the pod-manifest-path? In the docs they have an example only for Fedora that isn't helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can find in [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/static-pod/):

1. Configure your kubelet daemon on the node to use this directory by running it with  `--pod-manifest-path=/etc/kubelet.d/`  argument. On Fedora edit  `/etc/kubernetes/kubelet`  to include this line:

   `KUBELET_ARGS="--cluster-dns=10.254.0.10 --cluster-domain=kube.local --pod-manifest-path=/etc/kubelet.d/"`

   Instructions for other distributions or Kubernetes installations may vary.
2. Restart kubelet. On Fedora, this is:

   `[root@my-node1 ~] $ systemctl restart kubelet`

If you want to use `--pod-manifest-path` you can  define  it in Kubelet configuration.

Usually it is stored `/etc/kubernetes/kubelet` or `/etc/default/kubelet` or  `/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service`

Comment: Any ideas where in the kubelet configuration it can be defined? Here https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/config-api/kubelet-config.v1beta1/ it simply doesn't exist. Other directives which have been deprecated as command line arguments (like cgroupdrivers) do exist.